# How are memory references located in a moving garbage collection implementation?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, garbage-collection

In a moving Garbage Collector, it is imperative that a precise method of distinguishing between which values on the stack and heap are references, and which are immediate values. This is a detail that seems to be glossed over in most of the literature I have read on garbage collection.

I have investigated whether assigning some preamble to each stackframe would work, for example, describing each argument before it is called. But surely all this does is move the problem to an upper level of indirecton. How does one then distinguish the preamble from the stack frame when traversing it for immediate values or references during a GC cycle?

Could somebody explain how this is implemented in the real world?

Here is an example program of this problem using a first class function lexical closure and a diagram of its stack frame and and parent's environment located on the heap:

**An example program**

```
def foo(x) = {
    def bar(y,z) = {
        return x + y + z
    }
    return bar
}


def main() = {
    let makeBar = foo(1)
    makeBar(2,3)
}
```

**Bar's stackframe at point of invocation**:

[image: bar's stackframe during invocation]

In this example, bar's stack frame has a local variable, x, which is a pointer to a value on the heap, where as the arguments y and z are immediate integer values.

I read that Objective CAML uses a tag bit for each value placed on the stack which prefixes each value. Allowing a binary ref-or-imm check to be made on each value during a GC cycle. But this can have some unwanted side-effects. Integers are restricted to 31 bit and dynamic code generation for primitive calculations would need to be adjusted to compensate for this. In short - it feels a bit too dirty. There must be a more elegant solution.

Is it possible to know, and access this information statically? Such as passing the type information to the garbage collector somehow?

Comment: As interesting study, see the development of the garbage collector in the `mono` framework.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate this.

Comment: The stop-and-copy garbage collection algorithm is just one kind of tracing garbage collection method, all of which determine whether an object is live by tracing references to it back to certain root objects. How these root objects are determined is not part of the garbage collection algorithm itself. There's lots of possible ways a value on the stack can be determined to be a root. An implementation can assume any value is a reference to an object. Or it could assume there aren't any at all, either by not having any objects on the stack or requiring that they be rooted elsewhere.

Comment: @RossRidge, Good point, I understand. I just thought i'd include this in my question to give it some context.

Comment: "An implementation can assume any value is a reference to an object." So what happens when it encounters an immediate integer value on the stack which has the same value as an address in memory which contains a value? How is this ambiguity resolved?

Comment: It's not, it's assumed to be a valid reference to the object.

Comment: I see. So not deallocating items on the heap perfectly between both heap fragments is considered a trade-off in order to favour fast and easy implementation of pointer chasing during each GC cycle? Couldn't this have the detrimental effect of actually increasing the number of items to copy to the next fragment during a GC cycle causing a crash. (Esp during the first cycle)

Comment: A moving garbage collector would have to not move an object ambiguously referenced from the stack. You probably wouldn't want to use that method of determining roots with a moving garbage collector. (Or alternatively you probably wouldn't want to use a moving garbage collector if you're determining roots impricely.)

Comment: yes, imprecise scanning is a tradeoff and yes it does have an impact on performance because you can't implement a semi-space GC that way / or have to maintain freelists around pinned objects instead of bump pointer allocation.

Comment: @Jake As to "How does one then distinguish the preamble from the stack frame", why would that be a problem is the preamble also contains, at fixed offset, the size of the stack frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Could somebody explain how this is implemented in the real world?

There are several possible approaches

- conservative stack scanning. everything is treated as a potential pointer. this causes a GC to be imprecise. Imprecise scanning prevents objects from being relocated, which in turn prevents or complicates the implementation of [semi-space/compacting GCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Moving_vs._non-moving).
- mark bits as you have mentioned. this can be considered slightly-less-conservative scanning, but it is still imprecise
- the compiler retains knowledge of the exact stack layout, i.e. where pointers are located, at any given time. Since this can change from instruction to instruction and pointers can also reside in registers this would be very complex.
  As a simplification it is only done for specific points at which all threads can cooperatively hand over control to the GC with a known stack layout when a GC is requested by another thread. This is called a safepoint (explained below).
- other mechanisms might be possible, e.g. partitioning the stack into reference and non-reference entries and always ensuring that enregistered references are also somewhere on the stack, but i don't know how practical that approach is

[Gil Tene](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mechanical-sympathy/GGByLdAzlPw/cF1_XW1AbpEJ) has a nice, albeit mostly JVM-specific explanation of what a safepoint is, so i'll quote the relevant parts here:

> Here is a collection of statement about "what is a safepoint" that
>   attempt to be both correct and somewhat precise:
>
> 1. A thread can be at a safepoint or not be at a safepoint. When at a safepoint, the thread's representation of it's Java machine state is
>      well described, and can be safely manipulated and observed by other
>      threads in the JVM. When not at a safepoint, the thread's
>      representation of the java machine state will NOT be manipulated by
>      other threads in the JVM. [Note that other threads do not manipulate a
>      thread's actual logical machine state, just it's representation of
>      that state. A simple example of changing the representation of machine
>      state is changing the virtual addresss that a java reference stack
>      variable points to as a result of relocating that object. The logical
>      state of the reference variable is not affected by this change, as the
>      reference still refers to the same object, and two references variable
>      referring to the same object will still be logically equal to each
>      other even if they temporarily point to different virtual addresses].
>
> [...]
>
> 7. All [practical] JVMs apply some highly efficient mechanism for frequently crossing safepoint opportunities, where the thread does not
>      actually enter a safepoint unless someone else indicates the need to
>      do so. E.g. most call sites and loop backedges in generated code will
>      include some sort of safepoint polling sequence that amounts to "do I
>      need to go to a safepoint now?". Many HotSpot variants (OpenJDK and
>      Oracle JDK) currently use a simple global "go to safepoint" indicator
>      in the form of a page that is protected when a safepoint is needed,
>      and unprotected otherwise. The safepoint polling for this mechanism
>      amounts to a load from a fixed address in that page. If the load traps
>      with a SEGV, the thread knows it needs to go to enter a safepoint.
>      Zing uses a different, per-thread go-to-safepoint indicator of similar
>      efficiency.
>
> [...]

Comment: In the case of mainstream JVMs, the third alternative is the one that applies.

Comment: w.r.t The first point. If an immediate value is considered to be a potential pointer and the data on the heap at that address is moved onto the other fragment and the 'pointer' is updated to represent this new address. Wouldn't this no longer preserve the meaning of the program, as an immediate value would have its data changed by the GC during the program life-cycle.

Comment: @Jake, i didn't say anything about moving, but i'll update my answer to clarify

Comment: @the8472 Why is the second alternative still imprecise?

Comment: @MartinBerger - It depends on how you implement the mark / tag bit.  Some ways are precise (and expensive), others are not.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks. Have you got a pointer to the relevant literature?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no.

Answer (score 4):

The answer above identifies the three main alternatives.  There is a variation of the 3rd alternatives that has been tried:

- Have the compiler partition / reorder the variables in the stack and object frames so that (for example) the reference variables come before the scalar variables.

That means that the type information that needs to be retained at runtime is a single number.  This could be stored in the frame itself, or as type information associated with the class or method ... in the normal way.  However, this introduces other overheads; e.g. the need for dual stacks and stack pointers.  Empirically, it is not a win.

Some other points:

- The problem of identifying references exists for all kinds of GC.
- If you go down the "conservative" approach, (where reference identification may be inaccurate), then you cannot safely compact the heap.  This includes all kinds of copying collector.
- Mark bits (unless they are hardware supported) can be problematic for efficient arithmetical operations.  (If you need to "steal" a bit to distinguish pointers and non-pointers, then arithmetical operations require additional instructions to compensate.  FWIW, the MIT CLU compiler used to do this ... back in the 1980's.  The CLU GC was an accurate mark/sweep/compact collector, but integer arithmetic was slow ... and I can't recall how they dealt with floating point.)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered another possible approach described as [Emery's Idea](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/classes/cmpsci691st/scribe/lecture4-gc.pdf):

> - Run two copies of a program.  When checking a suspected pointer check    both copies of memory.
> - If the int/pointer in question is the same in    both programs it is an int.
> - If the int/pointer has the same base but    a different offset then it is a pointer.

I can see this having significant performance overheads in real world examples but could be possible for sequential languages, or those which run on a single core concurrently in user-space using a reduction timer approach.

Comment: One problem with this scheme is interaction with the outside world: even something as simple as `println(4)` should not really be executed twice. You could contact Emery and ask him if he's actually implemented it, or knows of an implementation.